# Passing variable to PHP script using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example Ajax PHP Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form id="my_form_id">
            Your Email Address: <input type="text" id="email" /><br>
            <input type="button" id="ddd">
        </form>
        
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#ddd').click(function(e){
                    //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var email = $('#email').val();
                    console.log(email);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'http://localhost/script.php',
                        data: {email: email},
                        success: function(data){
                          alert(data);  
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above is the code from my index.php file. My goal is to pass an email address from this php page to another page titled script.php. My script.php code is:

```
<?php
session_start();

$emailAddress = '';
if(isset($_POST['ddd'])){
    $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
    echo "hi";
}

echo 'Received email was: ' .$emailAddress;
?>
```

When I run my index.php code it displays an alert with the email address being successfully passed through with the AJAX function. However, when I refresh my script.php page it doesn't display the email address. I am trying to display the email address on the script.php page so I could insert it into a sql statement. Any insight on what i'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to access the email address in your Ajax activated PHP with `$_POST['email']`. However, `$_POST['ddd']` will not be set.

Comment: You dont pass `ddd` you only pass a variable called email -> `data: {email: email},`

Comment: Change the button to `type='submit'` and change `$('#ddd').click` to `$('#my_form_id').submit`. You are not preventing default on submit, you're doing it on click of the button, so the page is reloading. Personally, I just wouldn't use a form. I don't like what they do on mobile with the Enter button going to a Tab button. Also, you need to test for `$_POST['email']` instead of `$_POST['ddd']`, like @GrumpyCrouton stated.

Comment: @StackSlave I changed the button to `type='submit'` and `$('#ddd').click` to `$('#my_form_id').submit`. However, the result still isn't being displayed on the script.php page. Is there anything else i'm still doing wrong?

Comment: You should just use `url:'script.php'`... but that's not the issue.  Just because you have previously had an AJAX result show up on a page, it doesn't automatically stay there *(as long as the Client has an internet connection)* upon reload of the page. JavaScript runs anew when the page is reloaded. In this case, you need to store the information somewhere. Use `localStorge` or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your button type to `submit` doesn't help in ajax. All you need is their ids.

[Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfKIe.png)

And also you don't need ajax for your situation. You will just need this `window.location=` to redirect the data to your script.php

This will be your index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Example Ajax PHP Form</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
     </head>
   <body>
      <form id="my_form_id">
          Your Email Address: <input type="text" id="email"  /><br>
          <input type="button" id="ddd">
      </form>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#ddd').click(function()
            {
                var email = $('#email').val();
                window.location="script.php?email=" + email;
            });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

And then this will be your script.php. I removed your if condition 'cause it prevents to display your email data. POST will be changed to REQUEST to get the data from the url.

```
 <?php 
   session_start();
   $emailAddress = $_REQUEST['email']; 
   echo 'Received email was: ' .$emailAddress;
 ?>
```

Comment: @prince thank you for your help. I tried to implement the changes you suggested however it still isnt displaying my email on the script.php page. Is there anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I edited and wrote your whole index.php file and script.php file. Hope it will work.

Comment: @prince it still isn't working. Is there anything else you could think is going wrong?

Comment: I am trying to pass the email variable so it will display on the script.php page. My goal is to insert this email variable into a sql query on the script.php page.

Comment: Alright cause you have an alert code in your ajax. Please click the image link I posted and tell me if that's what you want or not. Thank you.

Comment: I saw the image you posted. That part of my code functions I was using the alert to check if the data was passed through. Is there any way for me to get the email to display on the script.php page? This was my ultimate goal of this code.

Comment: Its still not displaying on my script.php page. Is this working on your end?

Comment: Yes it is tho. See the image link.

Comment: Thank you it works. I was wondering if there's any way to do this without the index page redirecting to the script page. For more clarity I was wondering if there was a way I could refresh the script.php page and have the email displayed there as it is dynamically passed with the ajax function.

Comment: I see. Aight please look at my other answer I tried what you want to do. No jQuery needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only 1 php file, then do this. Please review the changes. Changing your button type to `submit` is a must and also the `method=POST` in your form. No need for `id`, just `name`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Example Ajax PHP Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="POST">
         Your Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
         <input type="submit" name="ddd">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_POST['ddd']))
   {
       $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
       echo 'Received email was: ' .$emailAddress;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the input to button type="submit" then in the javascript, kindly check the .click to submit

Answer (score 0):

your question is still not clear the script you provide working perfectly ..

**but in your second part of question :**

> When I run my index.php code it displays an alert with the email address being successfully passed through with the AJAX function. However, when I refresh my script.php page it doesn't display the email address. I am trying to display the email address on the script.php page so I could insert it into a sql statement. Any insight on what i'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

that's true after ajax success will alert data.
but your asking after I refresh script.php it's should display the email address...

after you refresh the script.php there's now any saved email address to be displayed.. before refreshing script.php you should save email in database or browser storage.

**Third parts**

> so I could insert it into a sql statement

why you want to display email address and after that you want to insert into database..
you can directly insert in database after ajax success.. example
don't use it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table ".
               "(email) "."VALUES ".
               "('$email')";
               mysql_select_db('SOMEDB');
            $res = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
         
            if(! $res ) {
               die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
         
            echo "Entered data successfully\n";
            mysql_close($conn);
```